# What's the appropriate way to print a single character?

Tags: c++

Assuming I want to use C++ stream to print character 'c', what's the better way to do this, `cout << 'c'` or `cout << "c"`?

More particularly, is there any difference in performance between these two approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"c"` isn't a character but a "string"-literal. It implicitly contains a 2<sup>nd</sup> character (a `'\0'` which is not printed) to terminate the "string".

So use:

```
cout << 'c';
```

**Update:**

As a C-"string" is are more complex data structure (namely an array `char[]`) than a single `char`, I'd say at least theoretically printing the `char` should be faster.

Comment: @gx_: 1st thanks for the corrections in syntax and grammar. My update referred to C-"string"s (with C referring to the language, not the example's letter) in general and I do not see why to limit my statement to the subset of those being `const`, especially in terms of perfomance scanning them. Do I miss something (probably C++ish)?

Comment: Indeed, I was only thinking of _string-literals_ (in C++, `"hey"` is a `const char[4]`; in C, for historical reasons, it's a non-const `char[4]`, but any attempt to modify it yields undefined behavior). But the notion of “_C-strings_” is indeed broader (“a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character”), e.g. given `char arr[] = "hey";` (or `char arr[4] = {'h','e','y','\0'};`) I suppose that `arr` denotes a C-string too, so I'd say that you're actually right. :) My apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, it would be the first variant, because `'c'` is a single character, and `"c"` is not. Double-quoted string literals are null-terminated character arrays. The type of `"c"` is `const char[2]`, and it contains `{'c', '\0'}`.

As to whether there is a performance difference, you have to measure and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about performance then you should simply forget standard streams and go at a lower level. For reasons that are indeed not entirely clear to me the raw speed performance of `<iostream>` is very poor compared to `<stdio.h>` (this has been my experience in the past, stream input being the worst).

In general for I/O performance the best is normally to do explicit buffering. The output of a single char becomes then something like:

```
 buf[wp] = c;
 if (++wp == BUFSIZE) buffer_flush();
```

(and by working at the application level you can also improve a lot more by avoiding doing the test for every single char and by using asynchronous writes).

Comment: That's a good point. But it's kind of overkill for my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have noted, using `cout << 'c'` is the preferred variant, as it is less complex than a C-string. However, if formatting is unneeded and you simply need to write the character to standard output, it is better to simply use the low-level unformatted input functions and flush thereafter:

```
std::cout.put('c').flush();
```

Since formatting does not apply in this case, it is more efficient. Moreover, the character `'c'` (and anything else still left in the buffer) is flushed to the external output sequence, as it should be, because flushing a single character is negligible in terms of peformance.